# Extracting client_id and client_secret for jMeter script executed on a Kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, wso2

I am trying to execute a jmeter script from a kubernetes for a particular service that would require clientID and clientSecret as values passed through the body.

When I am executing the jmeter script via hard coding from a pod, that would extract the clientID and clientSecret from a already deployed Kubernetes applications/config maps, the jmeter script is working correctly.

[image: Without parameterizing]

But, When I am trying to execute the jmeter script via parameterizing using environmental functions(${__env(envVariable ,Varible, defaultValue)}) from a pod that would extract the clientID and clientSecret from a already deployed Kubernetes applications/config maps, the jmeter script is not working correctly as it is not able to extract the values dynamically.

[image: With parameterizing]

I would really appreciate the resolution to my query.

Comment: Are you creating environment variables from config map? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data

Comment: check by running the command `env` on the pod